# C Sqlite3, How to know whether a table is null when I use sqlite3_exec function with select statement?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have a select statement for SQLite3, I want to use sqlite3_exec function, how do I know that if after executing the sql statement, the result is 0 rows , no match found etc..
I can define a variable, change the variable in the callback function.
My code below:

```
  char *selectSql = NULL;
  int flag = 0;
  asprintf(&selectSql, "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id=\"%s\"", SESSION_TABLE_NAME, sessionId);
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db, selectSql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

  //if the flag == 0, there is 0 rows found;
  if( flag == 0){
    //do something;
  }
  //callback function
  callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
  {
    sessionCount = 1;
    //do something;
  }
```

### But I don't think this is a good idea, is there any good idea?

Comment: Could you add a small code sample of what you have tried to determine 0 rows found?

Answer (score 0):

A `SELECT` on an empty table will have no matches. There is no distinction between "0 rows" or "no match found". You can check if a "0 row" happens (and I'm assuming you say "0 row" when performing a `SELECT` on an empty table) checking `SELECT COUNT() FROM table`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sqlite3_exec` you can use prepare and step

`sqlite3_prepare` is very similar to `sqlite3_exec`

```
int sqlite3_prepare(
  sqlite3 *db,            /* Database handle */
  const char *zSql,       /* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
  int nByte,              /* Maximum length of zSql in bytes. */
  sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,  /* OUT: Statement handle */
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
);
```

next use an integer and set it `=` to `sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt)`

```
int x = sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt*);
if (x == SQLITE_DONE){
    //This means your query returned null
}
```

You could use this

```
sqlite3* db;
sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
char *selectSql = NULL;

asprintf(&selectSql, "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id=\"%s\"", SESSION_TABLE_NAME, sessionId);

sqlite3_prepare(db, selectSql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
int x = sqlite3_step(stmt);

if(x==SQLITE_DONE){
    //Do what you want to do if it is null here
}
```